# Trying to connect to the MONGODB but its not connecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I'm trying to connect to my database in MongoDB but its not connecting, I'm using this code(index.js)

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let app = null;
let port = null;
let MONGO_URL = null;



const initVar = async () => {
    port = 9000;
    MONGO_URL = "mongodb+srv://mc3453:xxxxxx@unify.dyadwbb.mongodb.net/customer?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
    app = express();
};

mongoose.set('strictQuery', true);
const connectDB = async () => {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect(MONGO_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
        });
        console.log('MongoDB connected');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

const listentoPort = async () => {
    app.listen(port, async () => {
        console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
    });
};

initVar().then(() => {
    listentoPort().then(() => {
        connectDB();
    });
});
```

**The connection string is:**
`mongodb+srv://mc3453:<password>@unify.dyadwbb.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`

The error im getting is:

```
Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT unify.dyadwbb.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (node:internal/dns/promises:251:17) {
  errno: undefined,
  code: 'ETIMEOUT',
  syscall: 'queryTxt',
  hostname: 'unify.dyadwbb.mongodb.net'
}
```

I even added my IP address but every time I switch back to that website it says your IP address is not there but again I added it back

[image: MY address is already present]

How can i fix this please help me fix this issue, I'm new to this please help me

Comment: You should do a low-level test to be sure you can A) connect to that machine, B) that the service is running on that machine and C) that it isn't a Node problem by using other tools to validate the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to uncheck the expiry button while setting up a new IP or else it will be removed from the access list after the desired set time.

[image: Network Access settings]